# Is it possible to clear a timeout or stop a timeout from within a set timout?

Tags: javascript

Bascically I have a set timeout and I wanna make it so that if during that timeout something happens I can end it. Here is the code.

```
        let QandA = db.get(`QandA`)
        QandA.forEach((element, index) => {
            async function quiz(message, element){
                let split = element.split('|')
                message.channel.send(`**${split[0]}**`)
                message.channel.awaitMessages(m => m.content.includes(split[1]), { max: 2, time: 5000 }).then(collected => {
                    if (collected.first().author.bot) {
                        return
                    }
                    if (collected.first().content === split[1]) {
                        message.channel.send(`Congratulations <@${collected.first().author.id}> You got it right`)
                        var ttttt = true
                        ttt()
                    }
                })
            }
            var timer = setTimeout(() => {
                quiz(message, element)
            }, 5000 * index);
            async function ttt(){
                if(timer){
                    clearTimeout(timer)
                    console.log('Done')
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: You dont need to worry about clearing a setTimeout. Because it is a one time action. You can return out from the callBack function to achieve the desired result.

Comment: I want to make it if split[1] is equal to collected.first() then move to the next part in the array, is that possible?

Comment: The thing is when you are inside the quiz function, the setTimeout callback has already executed. So after the quiz function finishes it will move to the next array item. You don't have to clear the timeout or anything.

Comment: The thing is I want it to finish early

Answer (score 0):

#### The `async function quiz` can be moved up above the `QandA.forEach`

You only need to define that function once, not repeatedly inside the loop.

#### Your code looks like your 5-second delay comes from within the awaitMessages function?

I say this because you are passing the 5000 ms delay parameter to that function. Why would you need to pass it, unless that function implements a delay? Presumably `awaitMessages` returns a promise, since you are using `.then`.

#### Therefore your `.setTimeout` is solely to delay the STARTS of each question, not their ENDS

Looks like you are setting the start times of each question at the OUTSET, by creating a series of setTimeouts with different delays.

Therefore I conclude that you are looking to see how to `cancel` the setTimeout's for later questions if, for example, the user wants to quit the entire quiz early?

#### Keep an array of the setTimeouts

When you want to shut down the quiz, you can cancel them all with a loop like this.

```
    const QandA = db.get(`QandA`)
    const questionStartTimers = []

    // ... other stuff here


        var questionStartTimers[index] = setTimeout(() => {
            quiz(message, element)
        }, 5000 * index);


    // Then when you want to "kill" all future questions that are waiting to be asked:

    questionStartTimers.forEach(timer=> clearTimeout(timer));
```

Comment: I want to end it early

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify? 1. Was I right in each of my interpretations of your question and 2. End what early? An individual question, or the whole quiz?

Comment: The induvidual question, lets say someone answers a question right I want it to immediately move on to the next question